# How is selection/picking supposed to work in Direct2D?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, c++-cli, direct2d

I want to move my C# application from GDI+ to Direct2D (C++/CLI wrapper) for performance reasons. However I don't know how to solve the picking part. I have some shapes and images that I can move around. Currently I do it with GraphicsPath.IsVisible most of the time. Do you know what would be the equivalent in Direct2D?

Comment: By "picking", do you mean "hit testing"?

Comment: yes, something like that. I don't know what would be applicable to Direct2D. in GDI+ you usually use Rectangle.Contains or GraphicsPath.IsVisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FillContainsPoint` or `StrokeContainsPoint` methods of shapes implementing `ID2D1Geometry` might work for you:

- **[FillContainsPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** - Indicates whether the area filled by the geometry would contain the specified point.
- **[StrokeContainsPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** - Determines whether the geometry's stroke contains the specified point.

I found these from the [Geometries Overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#geometric_operations).

Comment: (I've never used Direct2D, but these were the first things I saw that looked promising)

Comment: this is it! thank you for you efforts. I was reading MSDN for hours to be able to start code anything but I didn't come across the ID2D1Geometry interface.If I only had searched for "direct2d hit testing" I would have found it ;P it's even the first result. all the time I was looking for picking and selection and it yielded no useable results.